# Trouble debugging seg fault when using fscanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind, scanf

I get a segmentation fault on the fscanf line below. I added the character width for each variable to try and fix it so I don't understand why it would seg fault.

I read from a CSV file into an array of structs.

The struct is:

```
typedef struct Person
    {
    int ID;
    int salary;
    int deleted;
    char salutation[4];
    char firstName[21];
    char surName[31];
    char job[16];
    } Person;
```

I declare the array of structs:

```
Person* persons;
persons = (Person*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(Person));
```

And then use this while loop to read the CSV file into the values:

(i is initialised at 0)

```
while(fscanf(f, "%d,%3[^,],%20[^,],%30[^,],%15[^,],%d,%d", &inPersons[i].ID, inPersons[i].salutation, inPersons[i].firstName, inPersons[i].surName, inPersons[i].job, &inPersons[i].salary, &inPersons[i].deleted)!=EOF)
            {
            newID = inPersons[i].ID;
            i++;
            }
```

The segfault happens during the fscanf statement. I'm not experienced with valgrind but it gives me this error for that line:

```
==16810== Invalid write of size 4
==16810==    at 0x578215: _IO_vfscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==16810==    by 0x585368: __isoc99_fscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==16810==    by 0x8048951: loadDb (Database.c:23)
==16810==    by 0x8048711: menu (Menu.c:37)
==16810==    by 0x804861E: main (main.c:6)
==16810==  Address 0x27230128 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I also get these Valgrind faults for the same line:

```
==18457== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==18457==    at 0x405A215: _IO_vfscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==18457==    by 0x4067368: __isoc99_fscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==18457==    by 0x8048943: loadDb (Database.c:23)
==18457==    by 0x8048711: menu (Menu.c:37)
==18457==    by 0x804861E: main (main.c:6)


==18457== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18457==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x5C5E4128
==18457==    at 0x405A215: _IO_vfscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==18457==    by 0x4067368: __isoc99_fscanf (in /lib/libc-2.12.so)
==18457==    by 0x8048943: loadDb (Database.c:23)
==18457==    by 0x8048711: menu (Menu.c:37)
==18457==    by 0x804861E: main (main.c:6)
```

Comment: Also: this code ran fine in Windows but crashes in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an alphabetic or punctuation character where you should have a digit, you have an infinite loop and you overflow the bounds of the array of people that you allocated.  You should be checking:

```
while (i < SIZE && (num = fscanf(f, "...", ...)) == 7)
{
    ...process valid input...
}
...consider what to do here, using `num` to distinguish between EOF and failed conversions...
```

The fact that `valgrind` can't identify the memory is puzzling.  You've taken most of the relevant steps to ensure that you don't get buffer overflows (all except checking on the status of `fscanf()` properly).

Oh…you allocate `persons`; you're reading into `inPersons`…which is correct?

I think I would be writing a function to call `fscanf()` and detect and report errors, and then calling that from the `while` loop:

```
while (i < SIZE && get_person(&persons[i]) != EOF)
   ...
```

or:

```
while (i < SIZE && get_person(&inPersons[i]) != EOF)
   ...
```

This also allows you to switch from `fscanf()` to either `fgets()` and `sscanf()`, or `getline()` and `sscanf()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will make those changes but the seg fault didn't appear in Windows with the same input, but appears in Linux. I added 2 more faults from Valgrind for that line in the OP.

Comment: persons is passed to the reading function which has parameter (Person *inPersons)

Comment: You've got some serious problems somewhere.  You've managed to screw something up royally.  Time to ignore the fact that it worked on Windows and start on an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Take your existing program, and start removing code.  Remove code after the site reported by `valgrind`.  Then try to remove code from before the site reported.  Make sure you get the same error (albeit at a different address) after you remove the code.  When you can't remove anything without losing the error, you have your best shot at an SSCCE.  Post the code.

Comment: OK, I have done this, I will post a new question as it will get too messy otherwise.

Comment: OK.  One other suggestion: make sure you're compiling with GCC set fussy and that there are no compilation warnings.  I routinely use: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition`, and if that isn't clean, the code isn't run.  (I don't run the code until I've fixed the warnings.)  You can choose `-std=c99` if you prefer (or even `-std=c89`).  But if there are warnings from that, the chances are that one of those is underlying the fault you're running into.